# IE8 Object Doesn't Support Method... ".closest()"

Tags: jquery, closest

Hate to bother all with what must be simple, but I keep getting an IE8 unsupported property or method error from the following code.  Works fine in FireFox.

```
    compName = comps[index].getElementsByTagName("compName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    compDesc = comps[index].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    nextCluster = comps[index].closest("skillCluster").getElementsByTagName("skillName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

    <factor>
        Gets Results
    </factor>
    <skillCluster>
        <skillName>
            Works Effectively and Efficiently
        </skillName>
        <competency id="25">
            <compName>
                Plans and Aligns
            </compName>
            <description>
                Planning and prioritizing work to meet commitments aligned with organizational goals.
            </description>
        </competency>
        <competency id="27">
            <compName>
                Resourcefulness
            </compName>
            <description>
                Securing and deploying resources effectively and efficiently.
            </description>
        </competency>
    </skillCluster>
```

The third line contains the error.  Array/nodelist comps[] is the result from a previous search for "competency" tags in an XML doc.  Structure of local XML is shown.  Stepwise removal of ALL other parts of the line except .closest() returns at least an object (via alert) and no error.  Other parts compName and compDesc working fine.  I am after the text innards in all cases.  Any help, AS ALWAYS, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `closest` method is a jQuery method, so you need to create a jQuery object containing the element to use it. The result is another jQuery object, so you need a `[0]` to get the element from it:

```
nextCluster = $(comps[index]).closest("skillCluster")[0].getElementsByTagName("skillName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: Yes!  I am not worthy.  So... javascript methods can be performed on jQuery derived objects, but not the reverse?  Either way, thank you.

Comment: @theDickChuck: No, jQuery objects and element objects have their own sets of methods. A few have the same names with the same basic functionality (for example the `click()` method), but they are still separate methods.